# Erro ao criar tabelas com relacionamento e JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-jpa, flyway

Bom dia, estou tentando criar duas tabelas com flyway+Spring+SqlServer+JPA, coisa bem simples mesmo apenas para passar o tempo e estou tendo um erro que não consigo entender pois se executar o mesmo direto no Sql funciona.
Tenho as Seguinte classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLC_DADOS")
public class PlcDados {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min= 3, max = 100)
@Column(name = "Descricao")
private String descricao;

@Column(name = "Fabricante")
private String fabricante;
//get set
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TAGS")
public class Tags {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min= 3, max = 100)
@Column(name = "Descricao")
private String descricao;

@Column(name = "Endereco")
private String endereco;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PLC_DADOS_Id")
private PlcDados plcDados;
//get set
}
```

A query vai via FlyWay

```
CREATE TABLE PLC_DADOS
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Descricao VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Localizacao VARCHAR(30),
    Fabricante VARCHAR(30)
)
CREATE TABLE TAGS
(
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Descricao VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Endereco VARCHAR(80),
    PLC_DADOS_Id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(PLC_DADOS_Id) REFERENCES PLC_DADOS(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Só que ao executar tenho esse erro:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'FKgr5o6gxoshp92e6v06sf8orbg' is not a constraint.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:845) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:752) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:729) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not drop object 'plc_dados' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:845) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:752) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:729) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'plc_dados' in the database.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:845) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:752) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:729) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: cara, aparentemente é porque a tabela plc_dados já existe no banco, quando ele tenta deletar ele cai nessa exception porque ela está como foreign key na outra tabela, tenta mudar só a ordem das querys aí rapidão e vê o que acontece.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém mesmo eu excluindo o banco de dados, acontece esse erro.

Comment: Entendi, você chegou a ver se depois de deletado ele está criando denovo? O que pode estar acontecendo também é que dependendo da configuração do seu persistence.xml ele esteja tentando criar as tabelas ao subir e estourando essa exceção